# Marketing Cloud - duplicate primary key on event data update

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions, journeybuilder

I have set up a Data Extension that contains my custom data for Accounts, with a field 'ContactID' that is set as a primary key and mapped to SubscriberKey. I have then created a Journey Builder Event that maps to this DataExtension.

When the Account data changes on the back-end I do a [POST /events API call](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/routes.html#postEvent) to Marketing Cloud. e.g.

```
ContactKey=’myself@example.com’, body={"ContactId": "myself@example.com", "AccountStatus": "account_pending"}
```

The first time this works fine, but the second time I post an event on the same Account e.g.

```
ContactKey=’myself@example.com’, body={"ContactId": "myself@example.com", "AccountStatus": "account_ready"}
```

I get the error:

> "The event data contains duplicate value for an existing primary key"

How can I work around this error to get a second event triggered on the same Account?

Answer (score 0):

The solution we came up with was simply to remove the primary key constraint. This doesnt seem to cause any adverse effects.